# Laravel file failed to upload due to size

Tags: php, laravel, apache, file-upload, wsl-2

I am using Laravel as an API when I try to upload a file bigger than 2Mb I get error `file failed to upload`. I saw that it's related to php.ini file, I tried updating `post_max_size` and restart apache, but it didn't work. I don't know how to solve this error any help please.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux? Depending on OS and what apache you are using, you might need to perform additional steps. It could also be useful to share what value you updated the post_max_file size to

Comment: I am using wsl , after updating these values I restarted apache server but it didn't work. Is it because I am running laravel project locally and not deploying it to apache?

Comment: What do you mean by running it locally and not deploying to apache?

Comment: I thought I had to deploy project to /var/www and configure it with apache but I changed  the variables in php.ini but still won't work

Comment: It sounds allright to me. If you shut down your apache server, can you still reach your project via browser?

Answer (score 1):

To increaes file upload size in PHP, you need to modify the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` values in your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M

post_max_size = 10M
```

You can also do it via .htaccess file.

Use `echo phpinfo();` to check you variable values.

Don't forget to restart your apache service after changes.

Comment: I changed those variables but still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two php.ini files `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` that I was making changes to. But Laravel was using `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` and I had to `dd(php_ini_loaded_file());` which gives the path to the loaded php.ini file. After making changes to that file and restarting apache2 server the problem was solved.